# Why clojure.xml/emit prints new lines around string contents inside tags?

Tags: xml, clojure

The `clojure.xml/emit` prints a newline around a string content in a tag like this.

```clj
user=> (require '[clojure.xml :as xml])
user=> (xml/emit-element {:tag :example :content ["Example"]})
<example>
Example
</example>
nil
```

I expect `"<example>Example</example>"`, not `"<example>\nExample\n</example>"`.

The XML specification says :

> #### 2.10 White Space Handling
>
> An XML processor must always pass all characters in a document that are not markup through to the application. A validating XML processor must also inform the application which of these characters constitute white space appearing in element content.

[Extensible Markup Language (XML) 1.0 (Fifth Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-white-space)

So those aren't equal.

In the `xml.clj` source code they call `(println ">")` instead of `print`.

[clojure/src/clj/clojure/xml.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/30a36cbe0ef936e57ddba238b7fa6d58ee1cbdce/src/clj/clojure/xml.clj#L105)

I'm using a custom version to replace `println` to `print`.

I wonder why they print new lines. I see `git blame` but there's no hint. Anyone knows?

Comment: This is not an answer, but if you are serious about XML processing, do prefer the [data.xml](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml) library. In my opinion `clojure.xml` is more a toy XML implementation compared to data.xml. In any case, data.xml seems to do the right thing (no newlines).

Comment: Thank you. I know about `data.xml` and I confess I'm not trying it because I'm making a toy. `clojure.xml` works fine except XML namespace even though its small code. `xml/parse` is perfect for me. It just returns a normal map & vector. `clojure.xml` is such a  great, so I have that question.